# i got an error "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND {{url}}" when running collection by using newman

Tags: automation, postman, postman-collection-runner, newman, postman-newman

I am new to Newman package execution with postman collection. I have done the following steps to run the postman collection using Newman package, but getting an error

```
POST http://localhost:3000/login [errored]
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
JSONError in test-script"
```

I have one collection with some API's, which reads URL value from the environment collection
url and Value http://localhost:3000

command used to run the collection: `Newman run collection_name.json -e environment_collection.json`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2wV0.png)

would you please advice

Comment: I guess the most basic question is, is the local server running? What do you have in the test script of that request? Have you tried running the Newman command with the `-k` flag?